# is there a way to view coding in python pyc files?

Tags: python

I have python `.pyc` files that I need to open and view the coding. is there a program or a way to do that? I have read about uncompelled, but I don't know if that is a legit thing to download or not. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "legit"? It's perfectly legal, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Search engines give multiple answers for "decompile python pyc files". Try some and see what you like.